# Returning number of occurences with condition from list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to filter number from list by condition that they have to be less than 3 and then how many elements like this were in starting list

```
filterLove :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
filterLove [42, 66, 15, 2] ~>* 1
```

I tried this `filterLove filter (< 3) a  = length a`  but it doesn't work. I can't figure out how would i do it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filterLove` is a function that maps a list of items so that means you define it as:

```
filterLove :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
filterLove xs = …
```

where `xs` is the list of numbers, and the `…` part is an expression that should have `Int` as type.

We thus create a new list with only the elements of `xs` that are smaller than three with `filter (<3) xs` where [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) takes a predicate and a list and produces a list with all the elements that satisfy the predicate. Then we can determine the length of that list with `length (filter (<3) xs)` where [**`length :: [a] -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) will determine the length of the list:

```
filterLove :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
filterLove xs = length (filter (<3) xs)
```

we can remove the parameter `xs` with an *η-reduction* to:

```
filterLove :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
filterLove = length . filter (<3)
```